# How to navigate a JavaScript project?

Tags: init-file, javascript, tern

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project using Backbone.js and I wonder how can I navigate between files, based on method and object definitions.

For example, I keep references to some of my views in the global object `App.Views`, and I would like to be able to navigate to each individual definition (`App.Views.Home`, `App.Views.SomePage`, etc.) if I encounter one. Also, there are a lot of closures used for avoiding namespace leaking, and I want to know how can I automatically follow these definitions.

I've seen [`tern`](http://ternjs.net/) but there are not many examples on how to configure it so I have not been able to do much.

What are some good tools for this?

Comment: "... but there are not many examples on how to configure it ..." -- Under the "Documentation" heading on the `tern` home page it says "The reference manual should be your first stop for **figuring out** how to use Tern." At least they're honest o.O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would absolutely recommend tern. I discovered it halfway through my internship (working in Node.js) last summer, and it worked wonderfully with `company-mode` and `js2-mode`.

`js2-mode` by itself is quite powerful. It can handle the usual `M-.` jumping within a file most of the time, and `tern` complements it nicely with inter-file/module jumping (esp. in the node ecosystem).

The first step to using tern is installing the binary. I personally used npm to do so:

```
$ sudo npm install -g tern
```

Then install in Emacs. The relevant section from my `init.el` is:

```
;;; tern
(package-require 'tern)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
```

The final step is to set up a `.tern-project` file *in the root directory of your project*. For Node.js projects, I use this as a starting point:

```
{
    "loadEagerly": [
        "src/**.js"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "node": {
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `company-mode`, then installing `company-tern` is also highly recommended:

```
(package-require 'company-tern)
(eval-after-load 'company
    '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern))
```

As a note, I did have some trouble with the tern server occasionally dying this past summer (2014). Running the following fixed it consistently:

```
M-: (delete-process "Tern") RET
```

I wasn't able to figure out exactly what was causing it, but it happened infrequently enough to be little more than a nuisance.

References:

- [js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode)
- [the `.tern-project` file](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#configuration)

Comment: This looks pretty much like the configuration I got. The thing is I'm almost always prompted with *No definition found*. That's why I thought there may be something wrong with my configuration.


For example, in one file I have `app.eventBus = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);` and in another I have `app.eventBus.trigger("changeURL","");`. But when I do `tern-find-definition` for my latter `eventBus` I get *No definition found*. 

Is there something I do wrong, or is just `tern` not supporting the kind of behaviour I imagine it would support?

Comment: With some frontend frameworks it has issues. It was almost always unable to figure out what to do with Angular (although I avoided the Angular bits and didn't try to figure out how to make it work with them). If the files are not referencing each other via RequireJS-style calls then you'll have to do more digging. It looks like [somebody got it working (?)](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/issues/95) but I don't have enough experience with that to tell.