# Emacs as JavaScript IDE. What is the best package for this?

Tags: javascript

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

I want to write many JavaScript files on Emacs. And as result I need comfortable mode to work with javascript.

So as result I want to use Emacs as JavaScript IDE. The question is: What is a good  package for this (with highlighting, context help, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

The current favourites are js-2mode and Indium.
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryJavaScript

The accepted answer here: [How to navigate a JavaScript project?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/how-to-navigate-a-javascript-project?rq=1)
provides a very nice Javascript IDE in emacs by combining `tern` for jumping to definitions in your javascript with `js2-mode` for live-preview of the results.

Comment: While this post technically answers the question, it would be much better if you explained why these two are “current favourites”, what they can do, and why one might prefer one or the other.